# Namimg of Karan in the Mahabarath?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, sanskrit, name, karna

In the Hindu epic of Mahabharat, Karan (Karna) is described as a great warrior. In accordance with the Sanskrit grammar, is the name 'Dhanveera Radheya Karna correct'? Or, if not, how should it be said respectfully?

Comment: Please elaborate ur question. Do u want to know about the names used to refer karna in Mahabharata?? Or how he got those names??

Comment: @ Sanatan Darshan, My humble doubt is:  Karan is known by various names but if we combine the names Dhanveera ( which translates to generous Donor) along with Radheya Karna (Son of Radhey) in doing so will it be appropriate or not in accordance with Sanskrit grammar?

Comment: I do not think Mahabharata call karna danveer anywhere

Comment: Is this really about the Hindu religion, or more a Sanskrit question?